# Disable Zero-Crossing Detection for specific subsystem only

Tags: matlab, simulink

Trying to disable the Zero-Crossing detection for only a given subsystem ( [User-defined Matlab Function Block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/creating-an-example-model-that-uses-a-matlab-function-block.html)) in my simulink Model, I referred to the [Matlab Central Guide](http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2013/04/26/zero-crossing-detection-what-are-your-options/), however, for User-defined blocks, this option is not available from the block parameters Menu.

Does any one have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out, MATLAB Function blocks are not part of the [blocks that register zero crossings](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/simulating-dynamic-systems.html#bridiag-11). Your options are either to enable/disable all zero crossings in the configuration parameters or to use a Stateflow chart in continuous-time mode. Alternatively, you can put your MATLAB Function block inside an Enabled/Triggered subsystem.